# Using Excel worksheets as data source for another worksheet

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am creating a resource management excel to track the resources, projects, allocation of resources to the projects.

**Resources** has following columns: `Name`, `Age`, `Profile`, `Country`, `Billing`

**Project** has following columns: `Portfolio Name`, `Project Name`, `Product Owner`, `Scrum Master`

To manage the information efficiently I want to add resources in one worksheet, Projects in another and then want to add a third worksheet "Allocation" to use the data from  Resource and Project worksheet.

How can I link "Resources" and "Projects" worksheet to the "Allocation" worksheet? so I can select  Country/City and then all resources from that country/city will be listed in the drop down?

[image]
**Edit**: I can do this using VBA but looking for inbuilt features of Excel to make this happen.

Comment: I do not want to use VBA and think Excel has inbuilt functions to handle this

Comment: 1. If you don't want vba why to tag it? 2. What has been your approach?

Comment: Some explained sample data plus the expected output would contribute to a better understanding of field interdependencies and what you actually have in mind. If you are excluding VBA solutions, a working VBA code might be helpful to know your target. @Ram

Comment: @T.M. : Updated the question with an image. Hope this help.

Comment: So basically you need a copy of the resource sheet in the project allocation sheet "filtered" by country?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey: I just want to have the information from both master sheets in the allocation sheet. Ideally if I type the name, all matching names should be visible as a drop down on allocation sheet. and once the name is selected, other values for that name should be populated on allocation sheet.

Comment: According to the information you've granted, the Name data is avaiable only in the Resource Master sheet. Therefore one can have a match only with the data in said sheet, not with the data in Project Master sheet. Same can be said for the Country data, which you've indicated previously as your criteria to create the dropdown (but now it has changed to Name, apparently). Since one can't involve the Project Master sheet, the answer that i've granted is still valid. Just change 'Resource Master'!$D:$D into 'Resource Master'!$A:$A to focus it on names.

Comment: If that's not the solution you are looking for, please clarify your request and preferably add some reproducible example with source data (devoided of any personal or sensible data) and expected result. Don't forget to show the cell's addresses (like in the images i've posted) so that we have a chance to provide a ready-to-be-implemented solution.

Comment: You are trying to use Excel as a database and Excel **is not** good for databases. I strongly suggest to use a different approach (Ms Access, SQL, and so on).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a Resource Master like this:

[image]

you can create a table in Project Allocation like this:

[image]

with these formula:

| CELL | FORMULA/VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A2 | *Your input* |
| B2 | =IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)>COUNTA(C:C)-1,"Alert: " & COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)-COUNTA(C:C)+1 & " results not included","") |
| C2 | =IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$2='Resource Master'!$D:$D)*ROW('Resource Master'!$D:$D),ROW(C2)-ROW($C$2)+1),COLUMN(C2)-COLUMN($C$2)+1),"") |

Drag the C2 cell to cover the rest of the table. The B2 cell checks if the (whole) column C contains less result than expected.

---

## FORMULAS EXPLANATIONS

### **CELL B2**

**EVOLUTION:**

**1) Mission statement**

CHECK HOW MANY (IF ANY) RESULTS ARE MISSING

**2) Breaking up the mission statement**

=IF(MISSING RESULT COUNT, ALERT, NO ALERT)

**3) Breaking up MISSING RESULT COUNT**

=IF(`MATCHES FOUND IN RESOURCE MASTER > REPORTED RESULTS`, ALERT, NO ALERT)

**4) Breaking up MATCHES FOUND IN RESOURCE MASTER**

=IF(`COUNTIF(RANGE WITH THE COUNTRY IN RESOURCE MASTER, CRITERIA)` > REPORTED RESULTS, ALERT, NO ALERT)

**5) Specifying RANGE WITH THE COUNTRY IN RESOURCE MASTER**

=IF(COUNTIF(`'Resource Master'!D:D`, CRITERIA) > REPORTED RESULTS, ALERT, NO ALERT)

**6) Specifying CRITERIA**

=IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,`A2`) > REPORTED RESULTS, ALERT, NO ALERT)

**7) Breaking up REPORTED RESULTS**

=IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2) > `COLUMN C VALUES COUNT - HEADER COUNT`, ALERT, NO ALERT)

**8) Translating COLUMN C VALUES COUNT**

=IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)>`COUNTA(C:C)` - HEADER COUNT, ALERT, NO ALERT)

**9) Specifying HEADER COUNT**

=IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)>COUNTA(C:C)-`1`, ALERT, NO ALERT)'

**10) Breaking up ALERT**

=IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)>COUNTA(C:C)-1, `"Alert: " & MATCHES FOUND IN RESOURCE MASTER - REPORTED RESULTS & " results not included"`, NO ALERT)

**11) Breaking up MATCHES FOUND IN RESOURCE MASTER - REPORTED RESULTS (similar but not equal to points from 3 to 9)**

=IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)>COUNTA(C:C)-1,"Alert: " & `COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)-COUNTA(C:C)+1` & " results not included", NO ALERT)

**12) Specifying NO ALERT**

=IF(COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)>COUNTA(C:C)-1,"Alert: " & COUNTIF('Resource Master'!D:D,A2)-COUNTA(C:C)+1 & " results not included",`""`)

**EXPLODED VERSION:**

```
=IF(
    COUNTIF(
            'Resource Master'!D:D,
            A2
           )
    >COUNTA(
            C:C
           )
    -1,
    "Alert: " & COUNTIF(
                        'Resource Master'!D:D,
                        A2
                       )
                -COUNTA(
                        C:C
                       )
                +1 & " results not included",
    ""
   )
```

---

### **CELL C2**

**EVOLUTION:**

**1) Mission statement**

REPORT THE LIST FILTERED BY CRITERIA

**2) Using an IFERROR in case the formula returns error (possible cause: result overflow)**

=IFERROR(FORMULA FOR THE FILTERED LIST,"")

**3) Breaking up FORMULA FOR THE FILTERED LIST into an INDEX function to return a single data in each cell (1 result in every row)**

=IFERROR(`INDEX(DATA RANGE IN RESOURCE MASTER, RESULT'S ROW IN RESOURCE MASTER, DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER)`,"")

**4) Specifiying DATA RANGE IN RESOURCE MASTER**

=IFERROR(INDEX(`'Resource Master'!$A:$E`, RESULT'S ROW IN RESOURCE MASTER, DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**5) Breaking up RESULT'S ROW IN RESOURCE MASTER into an AGGREGATE function to filter the data list in Resource Master**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,`AGGREGATE( SMALL , NO ERRORS, FILTER, DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER)`, DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**6) Specifying SMALL and NO ERRORS (aggreagate function argument)**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(`15`,`6`, FILTER, DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER), DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**7) Breaking up FILTER**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6, `LIST WITH ERRORS AND RESULTS * ROW COUNTER LIST`, DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER), DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**8) Breaking up LIST WITH ERRORS AND RESULT**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,`1/(CRITERIA = RANGE WITH THE COUNTRY IN RESOURCE MASTER)` * ROW COUNTER LIST, DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER), DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**9) Specifying CRITERIA**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(`$A$2` = RANGE WITH THE COUNTRY IN RESOURCE MASTER) * ROW COUNTER LIST, DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER), DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**10) Specifying RANGE WITH THE COUNTRY IN RESOURCE MASTER**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$2=`'Resource Master'!$D:$D`) * ROW COUNTER LIST, DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER), DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**11) Breaking up ROW COUNTER LIST and specifying RANGE WITH THE COUNTRY IN RESOURCE MASTER**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$2='Resource Master'!$D:$D)*`ROW('Resource Master'!$D:$D)`, DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER), DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER),"")

**12) Breaking up DYNAMIC ROW COUNTER and DYNAMIC COLUMN COUNTER into self-referencing row and column calculation; this allows the formula to be dragged to cover multiple results and all their data**

=IFERROR(INDEX('Resource Master'!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$2='Resource Master'!$D:$D)*ROW('Resource Master'!$D:$D),`ROW(C2)-ROW($C$2)+1`),`COLUMN(C2)-COLUMN($C$2)+1`),"")

**EXPLODED VERSION:**

```
=IFERROR(
         INDEX(
               'Resource Master'!$A:$E,
                AGGREGATE(
                          15,
                          6,
                          1/(
                             $A$2='Resource Master'!$D:$D
                            )
                          *ROW(
                               'Resource Master'!$D:$D
                              ),
                          ROW(
                              C2
                             )
                          -ROW(
                               $C$2
                              )
                          +1
                         ),
                COLUMN(
                       C2
                      )
                -COLUMN(
                        $C$2
                       )
                +1
              ),
         ""
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Data Validation to create dropdown lists?

1. Select the column or cell that you want to have dropdown lists for selection.
2. Click the **Data** menu.
3. Click **Data Validation**.
4. Select **List** in Allow:.
5. Click the up arrow and in Source, then select the values that you want to appear in the dropdown list then click the down arrow button, or enter the range.
6. Click **OK**.
7. To remove the dropdown list from a header, select the cell, click Data Validation, click Clear All, then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong tool for the task.
Have you heard about MS Project? Has built-in features to handle all that and more and also talks the management lingo.

Anyway if you still want to stick with Excel, you could use some named ranges and lookups mixed with indirect and offsets inside array R1C1 formulas.

More modern approach would be to use data model/power query after defining these tables.

But most important than any of these suggestions is you need to state your model more precisely first, you must define which are the primary and foreign keys for your 'tables' so you can work after.  In a SQL statement it would be the JOIN xxx ON yyy=zzz stuff...